# LIBGDX Box2D World QueryAABB not working

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, aabb

So I tried to get the bodys in my world in a range, which is a `square(AABB)`.

This is my Code:

```
public List<MovableObject> getObjectsInRange(float x, float y, float x2, float y2) {
    final List<Fixture> list = new ArrayList<Fixture>();
    world.QueryAABB(new QueryCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {
            System.out.println(fixture);
            list.add(fixture);
            return true;
        }
    }, x, y, x2, y2);
    List<MovableObject> l = new ArrayList<MovableObject>();
    for (Fixture fixture : list) {
        l.add((MovableObject) fixture.getBody().getUserData());
    }
    return l;
}
```

But what this actually does, is, I only get a report if the `AABB` is directly inside the fricture. I've got some images to show you what I mean.

Not working:
[image: Not working :(]

Working:
[image: Working :)]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, because of the upside down y system of libgdx, I had to modify it the following way

```
public List<MovableObject> getObjectsInRange(float x, float y, float x2, float y2) {
    final List<Fixture> list = new ArrayList<Fixture>();
    world.QueryAABB(new QueryCallback() {
        @Override
        public boolean reportFixture(Fixture fixture) {
            list.add(fixture);
            return true;
        }
    }, Math.min(x, x2), Math.min(y, y2), Math.max(x, x2), Math.max(y, y2));
    List<MovableObject> l = new ArrayList<MovableObject>();
    for (Fixture fixture : list) {
        l.add((MovableObject) fixture.getBody().getUserData());
    }
    return l;
}
```

I added Math.min and Math.max

Answer (score 0):

How are you calling `getObjectsInRange` ?
Because QueryAABB will only report objects that are inside the area.